# Python Pandas : filter a dataframe based on boolean pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, filter, slice

I know the topic is very well documented but I did not find a solution good enough. I have a boolean pandas series, myboolseries. I have a dataframe df. I want to filter df according to myboolseries (the index where the value is True).

```
myboolseries = pd.Series(data = [True, False, True], index = [2,5,8])
mydic = {"Age" : [14,12,55,22,98], "Name" : ["Pierre", "Mike", "Selena", "Victor", "Jesus"], "index" : [2,14,5,99,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydic).set_index("index")
```

Here is my solution (it does work), but I'm lookin for a more elegant way :

```
myboolseries = myboolseries[myboolseries].index
df[myboolseries]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.loc[df.index.isin(myboolseries.index)][myboolseries]

       Age    Name
index             
2       14  Pierre
8       98   Jesus
```

Answer (score 1):

if your Boolean series is the same length of your DataFrame you can just :

```
df = df[boolseries]
```

thats it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not the same length

Comment: each value in the boolean series represent a row ? what are the shapes of each object (dataframe and the series)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df.reindex(myboolseries.loc[lambda x: x].index)
```

Output:

```
   Age    Name
2   14  Pierre
8   98   Jesus
```